# How the connection is managed by data access application block in Enterprise library?

Tags: enterprise-library

I am new to entlib. I want to know how the connection state is managed by entlib, if I want to create a project which can be accessed by thousands of users is entlib data access application block better to use? Does it manage opening of closing of connections by itself?

Please explain me in detail...

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid this is not really the place for detail, however there is a free ebook called "Developer's guide to Microsoft Enterprise Library 5" which has plenty of detail. If you need more you can also download and examine the code for the whole library.

The main advantage of enterprise library is that it's easy to use, and does a lot of things you would otherwise have to re-implement in your code. Enterprise Library is part of Patterns and practices section in MSDN and implements well thought out and reviewed methods of carrying out common tasks.

Enterprise library helps to resolve ADO.NET issues, such as deciding how your code should call the close method, by automatically managing connections as far as reasonably possible.